# Query Table using any of the strings

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to filter table values. My code can only filter the table using one string/word. If you input multiple strings it will display no results. What I want is to display results using any of the words/strings I entered.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#getInput").on("click", function() {
    var value = $(myInput).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#table_filter_router tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

HTML

```html
            <form>
              <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon_left">
                <input type="text" class="slds-input slds-input_md" name="code" id="myInput" placeholder="Search router brand or model here...">
                <button type="submit" id="getInput" title="Search"><i class="icn icn-search"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
   
  <table class="" id="table_filter_router" border="0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th width="25%">H1</th>
              <th width="25%">H2</th>
              <th width="25%">H3</th>
              <th width="25%">H4</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
    <tbody>
            <!--sample-->
            <tr>
              <td width="25%">set1</td>
              <td width="25%">blue</td>
              <td width="25%">Four</td>
              <td width="25%">YES</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td width="25%">set2</td>
              <td width="25%">red</td>
              <td width="25%">seven</td>
              <td width="25%">NO</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML to the snippet? that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: Sorry. Just added. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Make jQuery :contains Case-Insensitive
    $.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
        return function( elem ) {
            return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
        };
    });
    $("#btn-search").on("click", function() {
        const searchVal = $(this).prev('input').val();
        if( searchVal.length == 0 )
          alert('please input some text');
        const $trs = $('table tbody tr');
        $trs.hide();
        $trs.filter(":contains('" + searchVal + "')").show();
    });
    $("#btn-multiple-search").on("click", function() {
        const searchVal = $(this).prev('input').val();
        if( searchVal.length == 0 )
          alert('please input some text');
        let words = searchVal.split(' ');
        words = words.map(w => ":contains('" + w + "')").join('');
        const $trs = $('table tbody tr');
        $trs.hide();
        $trs.filter(words).show();
    });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <form>
         <div>
            <input type="text" class="slds-input slds-input_md" placeholder="Search one word"/>
            <button type="button" id="btn-search"> Search
            <i class="icn icn-search"></i>
            </button>
         </div>
         <div>
            <input type="text" class="slds-input slds-input_md" placeholder="Search multiple words"/>
            <button type="button" id="btn-multiple-search"> Search
            <i class="icn icn-search"></i>
            </button>
         </div>
      </form>
      <table border="0">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th width="25%">H1</th>
               <th width="25%">H2</th>
               <th width="25%">H3</th>
               <th width="25%">H4</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <!--sample-->
            <tr>
               <td width="25%">set1</td>
               <td width="25%">blue</td>
               <td width="25%">Four</td>
               <td width="25%">YES</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td width="25%">set2</td>
               <td width="25%">red</td>
               <td width="25%">seven</td>
               <td width="25%">NO</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. but here's the scenario: If I search "set1 blue", it should show the set 1 column. Does it make sense?

Comment: So you actually want to search for multiple words, and use blanks to separate them, the query results show the columns where the searched words exist, am I wrong?

Comment: I wrote a piece of code according to the logic above, I hope it can help you

Comment: Hi Ian, This is working! Thanks for your help! One last, how can I make it not case sensitive?

Comment: Hi Mirokun, I adjusted the code, now it is not case sensitive.

Comment: Hi Ian, its working! Thanks much for your help :) Appreciate it.