# I'm having issues with this code and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, datatables

There is an error on line(s) 33 and 34 that say: "Line: 33: setImageURL() url parameter value (undefined) is not a string" and "Line: 34: setText() text parameter value (undefined) is not a uistring.ERROR: Line: 34: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')" I have a .csv dataset not shown but this is the information inside of it:

```js
[
  {
    "Color": "Red Line",
    "id": 1,
    "To/From": "North-South",
    "Images": "https://www.chicago-l.org/operations/lines/images/line_maps/RedLine.jpg",
    "From": "South"
  },
  {
    "Color": "Blue Line",
    "id": 2,
    "To/From": "West-O'Hare",
    "Images": "https://www.chicago-l.org/operations/lines/images/Ohare/Ohare.jpg",
    "From": "O'Hare"
  },
  {
    "Color": "Green Line",
    "id": 3,
    "To/From": "West-South",
    "Images": "https://www.chicago-l.org/operations/lines/images/SouthMain/SouthMain.jpg",
    "From": "South"
  },
  {
    "Color": "Pink Line",
    "id": 4,
    "To/From": "West Central-Downtown",
    "Images": "https://www.chicago-l.org/operations/lines/images/Douglas/Douglas.jpg",
    "From": "Downtown"
  },
  {
    "Color": "Yellow Line",
    "id": 5,
    "To/From": "Northwest-North",
    "Images": "https://www.chicago-l.org/operations/lines/images/line_maps/YellowLine.jpg"
  },
  {
    "Color": "Purple Line",
    "id": 6,
    "To/From": "North-Downtown",
    "Images": "https://www.chicago-l.org/operations/lines/images/Evanston/Evanston.jpg"
  },
  {
    "Color": "Brown Line",
    "id": 7,
    "To/From": "Northwest-Downtown",
    "Images": "https://www.chicago-l.org/operations/lines/images/NorthMain/NorthMain-Brown.jpg"
  },
  {
    "Color": "Orange Line",
    "id": 8,
    "To/From": "Midway-Downtown",
    "Images": "https://www.chicago-l.org/operations/lines/images/Midway/Midway.jpg"
  }
]
```

Here is the code itself:

```js
var lines = getColumn("CTA Lines", "Color");
var locations = getColumn("CTA Lines", "To/From");
var images = getColumn("CTA Lines", "Images");


var westImage = setImageURL("westLineImage", " ");
var westOutput = setText("westLabel", " ");

var linesFiltered = [];
var imagesFiltered = [];





function GetWestLine(){
  for(var i = 0; i< lines.length; i++){
    if(locations[i] == ("west")){
      appendItem(linesFiltered, lines[i]);
      appendItem(imagesFiltered, images[i]);
    }
  }
  }

onEvent("westButton", "click", function(){
  setScreen("westSideScreen");
  GetWestLine();
  UpdateWestScreen();
});

function UpdateWestScreen(){
  var index = randomNumber(0, linesFiltered.length - 1);
    westImage = setImageURL("westLineImage", imagesFiltered[index]);
    westOutput = setText("westLabel", linesFiltered[index]);
}
```

Comment: I have answered a similar question before, you can refer to [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61946367/query-table-using-any-of-the-strings/61995284#61995284), it should help

Comment: Oh you completely replaced your question, which makes my previous comment look a bit strange, how is your setImageURL and setText, appendItem implemented internally, you may need to give more relevant details, so as to help faster you

Comment: @Ian haha yeah, I realized the previous issue was rooted in a bigger problem, I'll try that though